# remove large gap in navigation menu

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

[image: gap picture]

I want everything to start on top. There is a large gap between the top and the menu

Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is my XML code

[image: xml code]

Comment: why do you have a view with layout weight 1 above Navigation View ? this is the problem. that tells the LinearLayout this view should take up all available space. remove that its not necessary.

Comment: remove view from your layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `View` with attribute `weight=1`. It signifies that it will take up all the remaining space.

If you remove that then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:layout_weight=1` from the xml.
As in [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight):

> This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen.